# Import media from ipod library

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, mpmediapickercontroller, mpmediaitem

i am the new for iphone programming.
i need to import media from iphone media library and copy to my app's document dir.
please help me.
thanks in adv.

Comment: When you say media library, do you mean iphone camera roll or are you talking about music?

Comment: What sort of "media" are you attempting to transfer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can transfer assets from the media library into your own app's directory, but you can playback songs, etc. via the [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). (See Apple's [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more information, if this is what you're attempting to achieve.)

The [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html) also contains information about accessing media in the iPod library and photos, etc. so you might want to have a read of this.

Comment: hi middaparka thanks for your comment but i seen this type of apps so any way to implement to it.

Comment: @prashant Are the apps you've seen on jailbroken devices?

Comment: @prashant As I asked in the comment on your question, what type of assets/media are you trying to transfer?

Comment: audio as well as video i  need to  import .the video is done but audio  i will struggling thenks